# Selenium Safari Time out using findElement.sendkeys

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to test my website with Selenium on Safari using Eclipse Luna.

My website uses Login with Twitter.
When I try to send key to an input on api.twitter.com I have a timeout.

Note that I have already tried "send keys" on google using the wiki page of Selenium even on www.twitter.com and it is working fine.

I do not understand why it is not working on api.twitter.com.
I thought the problem was my website, then I tested the same code on another website also using twitter authentication and I had the same error.

I even tried using javascriptExecutor to fill the value of the input and I also had a time out.

Could anyone please help me?

Please find below my code and the trace I have in my console.

```
package com.fxlabs.wonderboard.nodeTest;
import static org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Platform;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;

@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class BrowserTest {

  private WebDriver driver = null;

  private static boolean isSupportedPlatform() {
    Platform current = Platform.getCurrent();
    return Platform.MAC.is(current) || Platform.WINDOWS.is(current);
  }

  @Before
  public void createDriver() {
    assumeTrue(isSupportedPlatform());
    driver = new SafariDriver();
  }

  @After
  public void quitDriver() {
    driver.quit();
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldBeAbleToPerformAGoogleSearch() {
    driver.get("http://tweetbeam.com");
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs("TweetBeam Twitter Wall - Visualize Live Tweets"));
    driver.findElement(By.className("navbar-right")).findElement(By.tagName("a")).click();
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ExpectedConditions.titleIs("Twitter / Autoriser une application"));
    driver.findElement(By.id("username_or_email")).sendKeys("TwitterUsername");
    driver.findElement(By.id("username_or_email")).sendKeys("password");
  }
}
```

Failure Trace:

```
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out awaiting response to command "sendKeysToElement" after 30001 ms (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 30.01 seconds
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf323ce037c5f92db6c1bba601c2ac43ad8', time: '2014-10-23 13:11:40'
System info: host: 'xxx', ip: 'xxx', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.5', java.version: '1.6.0_65'
Session ID: null
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver
Capabilities [{platform=MAC, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, javascriptEnabled=true, secureSsl=true, browserName=safari, takesScreenshot=true, version=7.1.4}]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.sendKeys(RemoteWebElement.java:89)
at com.fxlabs.wonderboard.nodeTest.BrowserTest.shouldBeAbleToPerformAGoogleSearch(BrowserTest.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Did you try to increase your webdriver wait?

Comment: I have used the following line and it is still not working
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("username_email")));

Comment: Still getting same error?

Comment: Yes But I tried another solution. I log into Twitter before going to the API authent page. With this "Bypass system" I just have to click on the allow button. Selenium Team also answer that They had they same issue, but they managed to resolve it by  building and installing the Safari Extension manually from scratch.
See the link below 
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/458#issuecomment-110049297

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to send the email and password to the same field there aren't you?

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("username_or_email")).SendKeys("TwitterUsername");
driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys("password");
```

This works fine for me.

However be careful as the page behaves differently if it detects you are logged in to twitter already. You get a popup with some dialog welcoming you.

Comment: sorry for the mistake but it is not the problem but it is not working. Even the first field is not filled.